# Import CSV data into Excel from CMD (example given in Powershell)

Tags: powershell, cmd

I found a really good Powershell code on another post here on Stack Overflow. It's below; it loads .csv data in an .xlsx. It does exactly what I want. Is it possible to do this in CMD?  I've been looking for this in CMD equivalent but I only keep finding the powershell version.

```
### Set input and output path
$inputCSV = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\LSGTransactions.CSV"
$outputXLSX = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Book1.XLSX"

### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

### Build the QueryTables.Add command
### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
$Connector = 
$worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

### Set the delimiter (, or ;) according to your regional settings
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

### Set the format to delimited and text for every column
### A trick to create an array of 2s is used with the preceding comma
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

### Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

### Save & close the Workbook as XLSX. Change the output extension for Excel 
2003
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,51)
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: If you already have what you need why changing it? You could even run a Powershell script from a CMD batch file ...

Comment: Oh...that's a good idea. I know that I can submit CMD code to the place where this code will be called; I wasn't sure how Powershell code would fit in. I didn't think about calling one from the other. Thanks. It would be nice for learning CMD better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally COM Objects (Which Excel is in powershell) are not available in CMD

However a workaround could be to call a powershell script from the batch file, and pass the filenames as parameters.

```
powershell.exe yourscript.ps1
```

You may also need to set the excecution policy on your system, to enable running PS scripts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6)

Another kind of language supporting COM could be vbscript which you can run from

```
cscript.exe script.vbs
```

Comment: To avoid unexpected output, using `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\yourscript.ps1` may be helpful.

Comment: same with cscript //Nologo script.vbs